# Order by timestamp broken?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm making a "Recent Donations" tab on my website.

I've made the query like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM dc_donations ORDER BY DATE(dt) LIMIT 5");
```

But when i got a new donation today. It seems like it puts the new one, at the end (So the new one, is ordered at the end). My theory is, that it orders normally, and `2014-01-30`, comes before `2014-02-01`.

The "dt" column of the table, is a `TIMESTAMP` field, autofilled with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Did you try to set the sort order to `DESC`?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How should they be ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible problems with your query.

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM dc_donations 
  ORDER BY DATE(dt)   /* slow and wrong ! */
  LIMIT 5
```

First is that you're storing a full-fledged date and time, yet when you do your ordering you're only ordering by the date portion.  That's what `DATE(dt)` does.  This causes you two issues.  a) hopefully you'll have lots of donations, including newly arriving ones, in each calendar day. The way SQL ordering works, the server is allowed to order items unpredictably (randomly) if you don't completely specify the order. So your query will show a random collection of five old donations.  b) using a function on a column in an `ORDER BY` clause defeats the use of an index for that operation.  This could slow down your query a LOT as you scale up.

Second, do you want the five most recent donations?  If so, use `DESC`. You want this query I believe.

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM dc_donations 
  ORDER BY dt DESC
  LIMIT 5
```

Pro tip: Don't use `SELECT *` in production software. Instead, enumerate the columns you need to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't define how exactly you want it to be ordered (only by which column). So MySQL wrongly assumes you want an `ASC`ending order (smallest/oldest first).

This can be fixed by simply giving the correct order:

```
SELECT * FROM dc_donations ORDER BY DATE(dt) DESC LIMIT 5
```

But since `dt` already is a timestamp, you can save some time by ordering by the field itself instead:

```
SELECT * FROM dc_donations ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: It does the same, just reverse. - Edited main post for explanation

Comment: Yes, so now the latest donation is on top - isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Edited the main post now, so you can see what i mean. :)